# SSD status on Cisco ASA

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

How do I check the ssd status on a Cisco ASA firewall?

```
show configuration | inc boot
```

This shows me disk0, which I am assuming is the SSD, but is there a way I can get more information about the SSD?

Comment: What information are you looking for?

Comment: What model ASA? Every one I know of uses compact flash.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `show disk0: all` command. It will give you geometry, directory along with free space information and controller type/vendor. What else do you need?

### ASA 5505

```
sslvpn/example.com# show disk0: all
--#--  --length--  -----date/time------  path
...
129073152 bytes total (82755584 bytes free)

******** Flash Card Geometry/Format Info ********

COMPACT FLASH CARD GEOMETRY
   Number of Heads:           16
   Number of Cylinders       498
   Sectors per Cylinder       32
   Sector Size               512
   Total Sectors          254976

Flash Model: SMC128AFB6E
```

Comment: I added an example from a 5505. I can add a 5510 as well (it has 2 CFs)

Comment: The OP was asking about the SSD, not the compact flash.  The SSD is used for Firepower while the compact flash is used for the ASA's image and configuration.

Answer (score 3):

The question is specifically about SSD, not compact flash. The 5505/5510/etc series doesn't support SSD. On the newer -X series ASA, the SSD is used for IPS software. The SSD is not user-addressable for storage from the ASA CLI, so it won't appear the same way disk0 does.

ASA version 9.1(1) was the first to support CX, which is the prior (obsolete) generation of IPS product.

ASA Version 9.2(2.4) and up support FirePower AMP, IPS, AVC, and URL filtering, which is the current product line that uses the SSD.  "show module sfr" or "show inventory" will tell you if your SSD is installed properly.

References:

- [SSD Hardware Installation](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/hw/maintenance/5500xguide/5500xhw/asa_procs.html#63882) in ASA 5512/5515/5525/5545/5555-X
- [ASA Compatibility Matrix](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/compatibility/asamatrx.html#pgfId-132069) (search the page for "SSD")